# Spring Boot Validation Message resolve during compile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have set up Spring Boot Validation Message for i18n with the various annotations and beans necessary and have it all working for example

`SomePOJO`

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{user.lastname_required}")
private String lastName;
```

`messages.properties`

```
user.lastname_required=Please provide your last name
```

My issues is if I have a typo in the properties file or the POJO or just miss adding an message, this will only be discovered at runtime when the error is thrown.

Has anyone come up with a solution for how to discover this during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you excepted to load valid message dynamiclly .

you can add static constants which would define in  a  common constants class.

the code snippet is like following

#### step1. creat constants class

```java
public class ValidationMessages {
    public static final String LAST_NAME_REQUIRED = "user.lastname_required";

}

// In your POJO
@NotEmpty(message = "{" + ValidationMessages.LAST_NAME_REQUIRED + "}")
private String lastName;
```

#### step 2. load message from application

you can use @Value annotation on setmethod that inject value into a static field

```java
@Component
public class ValidationMessages {
    public static String LAST_NAME_REQUIRED = "user.lastname_required";


//  the message which behind ':' is  indicate default for the injection
    @Value("${user.lastname_required:last_name is required}")
    public void setLastname (String message) {
        LAST_NAME_REQUIRED = message;
    }

}
```

one more word ,
Define message in  spring `application.properties` ,bind the validation message lifecycle scope with spring application that i think it is not the best practise in product environment.  when ever you would like to change the  message ,  if there is no hot refresh spring config in no shutdown model ,  it should refresh config  via  restart application , if it is  frequently modified , it means that you would restart app in every modification.

The  validation message  should be  a constants , not load from anywhere dynamiclly

Comment: Hi Peng, but I need these error message to be internationalized, so they need to be dynamic

Comment: fine , just follow the step ,that would get your expected message